# Bind DependencyProperty to Label's Text property?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, dependency-properties

I would like to bind my `DependencyProperty` to a label of my custom button.

Here is my `DependencyProperty`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonText", typeof(string), typeof(MainMenuButton));

public string ButtonText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ButtonTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ButtonTextProperty, value); }
    }
```

And here is my attempt to bind the value to the label:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="lblButtonText" Margin="16,45.2465" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=ButtonText}" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Right" Foreground="White" FontSize="17.333" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" Height="26.053"/>
```

This way of binding my DependencyProperties worked several times in other cases but I can't figure out why it doesn't work this time?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The RelativeSource points to it self... Thus it is trying to bind to a property on TextBlock called ButtonText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the source of your binding to `Self`, and `Self` is a `TextBlock`, and `TextBlock` does not have a property called `ButtonText`

You're probably looking to set the source of your binding to a `RelativeSource` of type `MyCustomButton`

```
Text="{Binding Path=ButtonText,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyCustomButton}}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could try to bind like this:

First give your custom control a name:

```
<uc:myControl x:Name="ucName" ButtonText="MyText" .../>
```

(Remember to import the xmlns, which in this example is called uc)

```
<Window xmlns:uc="NamespaceToMyUc" ...>
```

Then bind to it using ElementName:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ucName, Path=ButtonText} ... />
```